# Update MySQL root password - Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-error-1064

I want to update my MySQL password from `I9O*Kez` ---> `SO123*`

I perform these

```
mysql -u root -pI9O*Kez

service mysql stop 
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -uroot

use mysql; 
delete from user where User='root';

CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'SO123*';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'%';
```

I kept getting

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Am I doing these completely wrong ?

It shouldn't be this difficult just to update a root password - right ?

Comment: Do I need to perform any of these ```service mysql stop 
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -uroot
```

Comment: [so] is for programming questions. [dba.se] is the correct place to ask database administration questions. There are many questions there about changing the root password.

Answer (score 0):

As the messages says, your server is currently running with the `skip-grant-tables` option enabled. This means your server is **completely unprotected** by any sort of credentials.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables

As you've disabled grants entirely, you cannot issue a grant. Since you know the old root password, you don't need `skip-grant-tables` to change a password; stop doing that. It's only necessary if you need to reset a *forgotten* root password.

You also probably don't want to delete the user at all - MySQL can use `ALTER USER` to safely *change* a password.

Comment: Can you please ... explain to me why would we need to do these `service mysql stop 
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -uroot` ? Is it only when we forgot the root password, and need to reset it ?

Comment: @kyo Running with `skip-grant-tables` means you can log in without a password, which is useful when you can't remember it. The rest are just basic "stop the service" and "log in to mysql with the root" user. You should **understand** the commands you're running before you go running them - it's very possible to irretrievably destroy data by blindly running commands from the Internet you don't understand.